# Разница построения отчета по схеме ДОКУМЕНТ – ОТЧЕТ и схеме ДОКУМЕНТ – РЕГИСТР – ОТЧЕТ в 1с

Tags: 1с

В чем разница построения отчета по схеме `ДОКУМЕНТ – ОТЧЕТ` и схеме `ДОКУМЕНТ – РЕГИСТР – ОТЧЕТ`? Какие проблемы первой схемы и достоинства второй? В чем разница использования физических таблиц регистров и виртуальных таблиц?

Answer (score 1):

В `1С` такие классы, как `Справочники`, `Документы` и их табличные части, хранятся в виде таблиц на `SQL` сервере (как и другие классы), но в отличие от `Регистров` у них нет дополнительных таблиц для для отчетов, таких как `Остатки`, `Обороты`, `СрезПервых`, `СрезПоследних` и так далее. Эти таблицы создаются платформой `1С:Предприятие` и служат для быстрого получения данных для отчетов, в отличие от основных таблиц.

Когда вы проводите какой-либо документ, или записываете элемент справочника, то записи попадают не только в основные таблицы этого документа или справочника, но и в регистры накопления, сведений или бухгалтерии, а вместе с ними в дополнительные таблицы этих регистров для удобства построения отчетов.

Схема `ДОКУМЕНТ – ОТЧЕТ` - берет данные из самих таблиц документов, схема `ДОКУМЕНТ – РЕГИСТР – ОТЧЕТ` берет данные из дополнительных таблиц регистров, что значительно ускоряет получение отчета.

---

При отмене проведения документа или установке пометки удаления, записи в связанных с ним регистрах очищаются. Таким образом в отчет по схеме `ДОКУМЕНТ – РЕГИСТР – ОТЧЕТ` они не попадут, а в отчет по схеме `ДОКУМЕНТ – ОТЧЕТ` попадут (но для них можно организовать отбор по полям `Проведен` и `ПометкаУдаления`).

Answer (score 0):

Регистры служат архитектурными швами.
На малых объемах данных разница будет не заметна, но трудозатраты для внесения изменений у схемы ДОКУМЕНТ - ОТЧЕТ выше.